# Send Customer Registration Confirmation mail using SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, email, customer-account, confirmation

I am trying to create API for customer signup. I works perfectly but now i need to add one more functionality. i want to sent customer confirmation mail when customer register. i have tried all but result are null.

```
$session =  $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);
try{
    $result = $client->call($session,'customer.create',array(array('email' => "$email", 'firstname' => "$firstname", 'lastname' => "$lastname", 'password' => "$password", 'website_id' => "$websiteId", 'store_id' => "$storeId", 'group_id' => 1)));
    if($result){
        $cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
        $cust->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');
        echo json_encode("New Customer created with Id-$result");
    }
}
   catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
```

My above code create customer successfully but not work for mail confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
$cust->sendNewAccountEmail(
            'confirmation', 
            '', 
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        );
```